# Cargo does not take changes from a local dependency. How to debug/fix?

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo

I have a project `main` that has a dependency on another project `foo` that I'm developing locally as well and is added via `foo = { path = "../foo" }` in my main project. The foo project has a `foo_rederive` project dependency (referenced via `path` as well).

I did a `cargo build` in `foo` and I was able to use the new code/derive macro in my main project. I then added code and any new code change is not reflected in main. I tried `cargo clean && cargo build` in all projects, but the code is not working.

My guess is that there's a build cache (I also tried `rm -rf target` in all folders, to no avail) or something else that prevents the build artifacts from being used.

How can I make my main project get any code changes I do in the local dependencies that I'm still developing?

P.S.: In case it's important, I'm using VSCode with rust-analyzer (both latest version).

**Edit:** It seems like restarting VSCode completely, fixes this issue. Now all code changes are reflected immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting VSCode completely fixed the issue, all code changes are reflected now (even new ones without restarting).